# Google Distance Api returns Zero with specific Latitude Longitude

Tags: php, google-maps

I am providing Origin Latitude/Longitude and Destination Latitude/Longitude to Google API.

But in response it returns Zero.

Provided Coordinates:

```
Origin       = 70.7417,-22.6583 

Destination  = 48.8602,2.34107
```

Output Result:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. 
The document tree is shown below.

    <DirectionsResponse>
    <status>ZERO_RESULTS</status>
    </DirectionsResponse>
```

Source Link:

https://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?language=fr&origin=70.7417,-22.6583&destination=48.8602,2.34107&sensor=false

Can anyone tell me where I am making a mistake?

Originally the points are form Danemark | Constable Pynt | 3985 | Gronland TO France Paris 75001 Ile-de-France

Comment: There is no mistake, the directions-service did not include directions where you need to travel by ship or plane(except some ferries). As long as nobody builds a bridge from greenland to eurasia you will not get a result for a direction from greenland to paris.

Answer (score 1):

"ZERO_RESULTS" indicates that the geocode was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the geocode was passed a non-existent address or a latlng in a remote location.

please try to check if you coordinates are valid.

Comment: yes but 48.8602,2.34107 is in Paris , 70.7417,-22.6583  is somewere in Greenland, the corrdinates are valid but the direction is unavailable from that 2 points

Comment: As I mentioned , Originally the points are form Danemark , Constable Pynt TO France Paris 75001 Ile-de-France.

Comment: Coordinates are valid. Constable Pynt 3985 is at Greendland which is part of Denmark (it has autonomy within the Kingdom of Denmark). And also [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/) reports *We could not calculate directions between 48.860200, 2.341070 and 70.741700, -22.658300.*. See comment from Dr. Molle.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that Google Maps tries to find a driving route between the two points. Since the locations you provided are in Greenland and France, with no direct connection, Google can't find directions, hence the response `ZERO_RESULTS`.

Quote from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en&csw=1#StatusCodes):

```
ZERO_RESULTS indicates no route could be found between the origin and destination.
```

Comment: Originally the points are form Danemark | Constable Pynt | 3985 | Gronland TO France Paris 75001 Ile-de-France